# Why can't I read messages from my Gorilla WebSocket server until it gets closed by the client?

Tags: angular, go, websocket, rxjs, gorilla

I have used the Gorilla Websocket [example](https://golangdocs.com/golang-gorilla-websockets)  as a starting point to implement a websocket server in go.

The client is sending a dataset in chunks, each chunk being a zlib compressed protobuf message. Each message is separated by between 1-2 seconds. I can see data being sent at the expected time in Wireshark. Currently this is a one-way data flow: messages are only sent from client to server for now. *Not sure if important, but the client is using RxJs Websocket in an Angular SPA.*

Ultimately, all the data is successfully received and decoded by my server, but despite my best efforts to make it process each chunk as it arrives (by kicking off a goroutine for each received message), it only occurs once the websocket is closed.

Can anyone explain why?

**Here's the function which handles the websocket:**

```
func socketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    enableCors(&w)
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true } //insecure!!
    // Upgrade raw HTTP connection to a websocket based one
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Error during connection upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Client connected to websocket")
    defer conn.Close()

    streamedBytes := 0

    // The event loop
    for {
        messageType, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error during message reading:", err, messageType, message)
            break
        }
        streamedBytes += len(message)

        go handleMessage(message)

    }
    log.Printf("Streamed %v megabytes", float64(streamedBytes)/1000000.0)
}
```

**And here's the function which handles receipt of a message by the websocket**

```
func handleMessage(message []byte) {

    t := time.Now()

    b := bytes.NewReader(message)
    z, err := zlib.NewReader(b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating zip reader")
    }
    defer z.Close()

    p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(z)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error unzipping content", err)
    }

    chunk := &DtmChunk{}
    if err := proto.Unmarshal(p, chunk); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to parse chunk:", err)
    }

    points := chunk.GetPoints()

    log.Printf("Streamed %v points at %v", len(points), t)
}
```

The message handling function prints out time at which it was called, and that shows that the go routines are all running at more or less the same time, rather than at >1 second intervals.

```
2021/10/19 14:47:44 Streamed 308404 points at 2021-10-19 14:47:44.0910448 
2021/10/19 14:47:44 Streamed 308405 points at 2021-10-19 14:47:44.178004 
2021/10/19 14:47:44 Streamed 308405 points at 2021-10-19 14:47:44.2718446 
2021/10/19 14:47:44 Streamed 308404 points at 2021-10-19 14:47:44.3723518 
2021/10/19 14:47:44 Streamed 178081 points at 2021-10-19 14:47:44.5507965 
2021/10/19 14:47:44 Streamed 308405 points at 2021-10-19 14:47:44.4770831
```

Edit: Posting client websocket service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject, WebSocketSubjectConfig } from "rxjs/webSocket";
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import * as dtm from 'src/interfacing/dtm';
import pako from 'pako';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const sleep = (delay: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay))
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileUploadService {
  constructor() {
    console.log("constructing: FileUploadService")
  }

  subject: WebSocketSubject<any> | undefined
  closeSubject = new Subject<CloseEvent>();


  initNewFileStream() {
    this.closeSubject.subscribe(_ => console.log('Underlying Websocket connection closed'))

    this.subject = webSocket({
      url: `ws${environment.serverUrl}socket`,
      binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
      openObserver: {next: () => console.log('Underlying WebSocket connection open')},
      closeObserver: this.closeSubject,
      serializer: (msg: Uint8Array) => {
        const offset = msg.byteOffset;
        const length = msg.byteLength;
        return msg.buffer.slice(offset, offset + length)
      },
      deserializer: v => v.data,
    });
    
    this.connectWebsocket();

  }

  finaliseFileStream() {
    
    if (this.subject != (null || undefined)) {
      console.log("Finalising file stream")
      this.subject.unsubscribe();
      this.subject.complete();
    }
  }

  connectWebsocket() {
    if (this.subject != undefined) {
      this.subject.subscribe(
        data => console.log('file-upload-component: Received data via subscription to FileUpload Service: ', data),
        err => console.log('Websocket reports error: ', err),
        () => console.log('Websocket closed - complete')
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Can't connect to websocket: Undefined.")
    }
  }

  send(data: any) {

    if (this.subject != undefined) {

      let anchorXmm = 1000*data[0][0];
      let anchorYmm = 1000*data[0][1];
      let anchorZmm = 1000*data[0][2];

      let anchorPoint: dtm.DtmChunk_Point = {
        x: anchorXmm,
        y: anchorYmm,
        z: anchorZmm,
      };

      var points: dtm.DtmChunk_Point[] = [];
      
      for (const [x, y, z] of data) {

        var p: dtm.DtmChunk_Point = {
          x: ((1000*x) | 0) - anchorXmm,
          y: ((1000*y) | 0) - anchorYmm,
          z: ((1000*z) | 0) - anchorZmm,
        }

        points.push(p);
      }

      let bytes = pako.deflate(dtm.DtmChunk.encode({
        anchorPoint: anchorPoint,
        points: points,
      }).finish())
    
      this.subject.next(bytes);

            
    } else {
      console.log("Send failed: websocket is undefined")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The program should process messages as the messages arrive. Log a message before the `go handleMessage(message)` statement to confirm that the application reads the messages with the timing that you expect.

Comment: Could you provide the code of client ?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I added the log message as suggested: No the timing is ~the same as the the timing logged by the goroutine. Suggests that conn.ReadMessage() isn't retuning anything until the socket is closed?

Comment: @emptyhua I have posted the client service code, hopefully gives you enough information.

Comment: The timing in the Go code does not square with the wireshark timing.  Because the Gorilla package does not buffer entire messages, the application will read the messages as the messages arrive over the network.  Double check the wireshark times.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I checked the Wireshark timing, and you're absolutely right - there was activity which mislead me to thinking the data was being sent when I expected, but it wasn't the data I thought it was. I traced it way up to code in my client app which was calling the websocket service incorrectly, so the problem is well outside the scope of my question. Thanks for your help.